# Create new variable by filtering from existing columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a DataFrame. I want to create a new variable based on each words length.
For example:

DataFrame:

```
            base
0        d4 d5 c4 
1        d4 Nc6 e4 
2        e4 e5 d3 
3        d4 d5 Nf3
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
            base       len2          len3
0        d4 d5 c4      d4 d5 c4 
1        d4 Nc6 e4     d4 e4         Nc6
2        e4 e5 d3      e4 e5 d3
3        d4 d5 Nf3     d4 d5         Nf3
```

I am new to python, This is what I have tried

```
df['len2'] = filter(len(df['base'].str.split()) == 2, df['base'])
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'base': ['d4 d5 c4', 'd4 Nc6 e4']})
df['len2'] = df['base'].str.split().apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if not i[0].isupper()])
df['len3'] = df['base'].str.split().apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i[0].isupper()])
```

The type of the output column is a pd.Series of lists but you can convert them

```
df['len3'] = df['base'].str.split().apply(lambda x: " ".join([i for i in x if i[0].isupper()]))
```

If your condition is that the length of each element is equal to 2 then

```
df['len3'] = df['base'].str.split().apply(lambda x: " ".join([i for i in x if len(i) != 2]))

        base len3
0   d4 d5 c4     
1  d4 Nc6 e4  Nc6
```